# Overlay variable youtube embedded video with image, hide image when clicked and autoplay without hardcoded jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I would like to display an image before viewing a youtube/vimeo video on my website. Is there a way to do this with jQuery or javascript?

I want to overlay this with my own image and when clicked, display the video and autoplay it, all without reloading the page.

The image and video data are coming from a database so the video data is variable. I already found a similar Question/Anwser on here:
[Overlay youtube embedded video with image, hide image when clicked and autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949783/overlay-youtube-embedded-video-with-image-hide-image-when-clicked-and-autoplay)

But my video's are variable. Is there any other way to change the autoplay value?

Thank you for your help

Regards Jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  overlay image you can simply use poster attribute and give path to your image

```
<video id="myvid" autoplay controls poster="/overlay.jpg">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

For changing video dynamically

```
var video = document.getElementById('myvid ');
var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
sources[0].src = "http://example.com/new_url.mp4";
sources[1].src = "http://example.com/new_url.ogg";
video.load(); //reloads video without reloading page
video.play();
```